# Different ways of declaring variables within functions -how do they differ?

Tags: javascript

I have seen two different ways to declare variables within functions. How do they differ? Thank you.

```
Namespace.Class = function() {
    // first way. use "var".
    var variable1 = 'value';

    // second way. use "namespace".
    Namespace.Class.variable2 = 'value';
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`var` declares a local variable, meaning it's only visible from within the function, while the second way is for declaring a member of the object, which will be visible from everywhere.

A tutorial on Javascript variables:
http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tutorials/javascript/global_local_variables_scope_javascript.php3

**Edit:** A tutorial on private members in JS:
http://www.crockford.com/javascript/private.html

Comment: "Member of a class" is incorrect. Javascript does not have classes.

Comment: The second way actually makes `variable2` visible to anyone who can access `Namespace`, since JavaScript doesn't have real private members.

Comment: Yes, Object is the correct term, and it will be visible to any scope that has access to `Namespace`